# Bootstrap inline form field not aligning top and bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem as indicated in the following image:

[image: City, State and Zip Code]

Obviously I want the state dropdown to align with the top and bottom of the other two controls. Here is the code I have used to generate this section of the screen:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtShipToCity" class="small-text-label"><strong>City St Zip:</strong></label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipToCity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-inline input-sm width-100 form-fixer"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlShipToState" runat="server" Font-Size="small" CssClass="form-control-inline input-sm width-50 form-fixer" Height="24px" ></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipToZip" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-inline input-sm width-50 form-fixer" maxlength="5" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
```

The CSS that is relevant:

```
input.form-fixer{
    padding: 1px !important;
    font-size: x-small !important;
    height: 24px !important;
}

.width-50 {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

All other CSS are standard Bootstrap 3 CSS classes.

How do I get the alignment I am looking for here?

ADDED: http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/2E9Sz/

Comment: Can you take the actual HTML output and post it into a jsFiddle or CodePen? its pretty hard to figure it out with server-side code.

Comment: General rule: if all your CSS properties are `!important`, you're probably doing something wrong. Make your selectors more specific and/or make sure they load after Bootstrap's CSS file.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle link in the original question. My CSS files DO load after the Bootstrap CSS files. the !important was added to see if it would fix the problem and obviously did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would say your input controls styles doesn't have look like bootstrap. The reason is you are using `form-control-inline` which didn't even present in `bootstrap-3.0` (make sure you not confusing with bootstrp 2.3)

If you use bootstrap recommendation correctly, you won't get such problem.

But here is the problem with this class

```
.input-sm
{
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

which defines in `bootstrap.min.css` file.
if you remove these padding you get your expected output. You can overwrite this class in your custom css file with `padding:0`.

```
.input-sm
{
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcZEZ/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You can **add padding: 0px** to element with **id=ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlShipToState**.

padding is causing the **issue: 5px** padding is added.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue at all.

Comment: use  padding: 0px !important;